# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string,

Tags: joomla

I'm getting this error

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /homepages/25/d695898710/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Joomla/prestigetaxisheathrow/components/com_sppagebuilder/parser/addon-parser.php on line 561
```

where line 561 is

```
$default .= ' '.$key.'="'.htmlspecialchars($val).'"';
```

How can i solve this error?

Comment: What kind of value are you storing in $val?

Comment: @Qurban Please temporarily hack the SPPageBuilder script by writing `JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage(json_encode($val), 'notice');` just above your erring line of code, then tell us what you see and what string value you intend to use. When you have Joomla support questions, please post them at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.